# Asymptotic growth relation between 2^n and 2^(n/2)

Tags: analysis

There's this question I'm solving where
`f(n) = 2^n`
`g(n) = 2^(n/2)`
`f(n) = ?(g(n))`
I've found many answers as Ω and ω.
But shouldn't it be `f(n) = θ(g(n))`? Since the constant shouldn't affect the growth of the function?

Answer (score 0):

`f(n) = θ(g(n))` if and only if `f(n) = Ω(g(n))` and `f(n) = O(g(n))`, but we can see that `f(n) = O(g(n))` just doesn't hold as explained below.

> O(g(n)) = {f(n): there exist positive constants c and n0 such that 0 <= f(n) <= c g(n) for all n >= n0}

2^n <= c 2^(n/2) would lead to 2^(n/2) <= c, and we cannot find such an n0 to make the above definition holds.

```
n = np.linspace(1, 10)
plt.plot(n, 2 ** n, label="2 ** n")
plt.plot(n, 2 ** (n/2), label="2 ** (n/2)")
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Reference: [CLRS](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262033844)